# Segmentation fault in C (generating strings, error occurs while I check for duplicates)

Tags: c, gcc, segmentation-fault

Here is a program which generates words like "aaabaabaaa" (or just empty string) following certain rules, everything works fine it generates it, sorts it by size and then alphabetically but when I implemented section that prevents from generating same words it gives me "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"

My question is what causes it and how can i solve it?

(I use Code::Blocks using gcc compliler on Ubuntu 14.04)

Whole program

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

void bsas(int n, char **words);

void as(int n, char **words) {
        int rn = rand();
        strcat(words[n], "a");
        if(rn % 3 == 0) as(n, words);
        if(rn % 3 == 1) bsas(n, words);
}

void bsas(int n, char** words){
        int rn, j;
        for(j=0; j<2; j++){
                if(j == 0)
                        strcat(words[n], "b");
                else
                        strcat(words[n], "a");
                rn = rand();
                if(rn % 3 == 0) as(n, words);
                if(rn % 3 == 1) bsas(n, words);
        }
}

static int compareCombo(const void *  a, const void * b){
        if (strlen(*(const char **) a) < strlen(*(const char **) b))
                return -1;
        else if (strlen(*(const char **) a) > strlen(*(const char **) b))
                return 1;
        else
                return strcmp (*(const char **) a, *(const char **) b);
}

int main()
{
        int rnum = 0, i, j, n;
        char** words;
        srand(time(NULL));
        system("clear");
        printf("\n Opis gramatyki: \n S->aS|bSaS|ε \n");
        getchar();
        printf("Ile chesz wygenerowac lancuchow? "); /*means how much words do you want to generate*/
        scanf("%d", &n);
        words = (char**) malloc(n*sizeof(char*));
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
                words[i] = (char*) malloc(40000*sizeof(char));
        }

        for(i=0; i<n; i++){
                rnum = rand();
                if(rnum % 3 == 0) as(i, words);
                if(rnum % 3 == 1) bsas(i, words);
                if(rnum % 3 == 2) ;
                /*:PROBLEM OCCURS when I add this: */
                **for(j = i-1; j >= 0; j--){
                        if(strcmp(words[i], words[j]) == 0){
                                words[i] = "";
                                i--;
                                break;
                        }
                }**
                /*
                   this should check if there are some duplicates among words
                   if there are any it should erase it, and try to generate it again
                 */
        }
        qsort (words, n, sizeof (const char *), compareCombo);
        for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
                printf("%d\t- %s\n", i+1, words[i]);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

The section when error appears:

```
/*:PROBLEM OCCURS when I add this: */
            for(j = i-1; j >= 0; j--){
                if(strcmp(words[i], words[j]) == 0){
                    words[i] = "";
                    i--;
                    break;
                }
            }
            /*
            this should check if there are some duplicates among words
            if there are any it should erase it, and try to generate it again
            */
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first i answered that you access words[-1] at first itearation but then saw that you check for j>=0..
I have 2 comments about your code:
after allocating each word, please clear your buffer - since you strcat the word it could lead to unexpected behavior and memory corruption.
do not clear the duplicated word by words[i] = ""; use:

```
strcpy(words[i],"");
```

this way you are not losing the allocated buffer that was previously pointed by words[i]

Answer (score 3):

There are actually two errors in the code.

The line `if(rnum % 3 == 2) ;` will leave `word[i]` uninitialized. You can then only hope that one of the 40000 bytes that you've allocated is a zero.  It's highly likely that there will be a zero somewhere in the buffer, but if not then `strcmp` will run past the end of the buffer, resulting in undefined behavior.

The second problem is the line

```
words[i] = "";
```

That's going to replace the pointer to the 40000 byte read/writeable buffer, with a pointer to a one-byte read-only buffer.  When you subsequently try to write to that buffer with the `as` or `bsas` functions, you will get a segmentation fault. One way to correct the problem is to use the following line to clear the word

```
words[i][0] = '\0';
```

But actually, you don't need to clear the word at all, since the buffer was uninitialized anyways, and you are decrementing `i` to remove that word from the list.